# How do I calculate the ground footprint of an aerial camera?

Tags: lens, calculations, aerial-photography

I have a very simple math problem, but I cannot seem to figure it out. I need to calculate what portion of the ground will be visible when viewed from a UAV mounted camera. I believe I have it solved for looking straight down, but the camera is on a gimbal and will have a full range of motion in all axes.

The inputs to the problem will be the Altitude (m), camera focal length (mm), camera sensor x length (mm), camera sensor y length (mm), and the angle of tilt in each plane.

Here is what I have for when the camera is pointed straight down (Note: this gives me the length of each side of ground coverage. Ideally, I would like to have each point, in this case, the four corners of the rectangle.)

Ground distance in X plane = (Altitude / focal length of lens) * X length of camera sensor

Ground distance in Y plane = (Altitude / focal length of lens) * Y length of camera sensor

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I got a little carried away with formatting my answer...

[image]

[image]

This drawing is adaptable and can automatically calculate different scenarios, I'll give LaTeX/Python source to anyone who wants it.

Edit: [I've put the source code here.](https://github.com/mountainunicycler/dronecamerafov/tree/master) I must warn potential viewers that it's difficult to read and badly formatted because of nesting python inside LaTeX.

Comment: Despite the great explanation (+1), there's a [new question related to the details of it](http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/82402/35348). Could you please take a look @Ryan?

Comment: I don't think you are using the y-axis gimbal the way you think you are. How can the distance from drone to left of picture be *less* than the perpendicular distance from the drone to the ground? The length of the hypotenuse of a right triangle can *never* be less than the length of either side.

Comment: Shouldn't the footprint be a trapezoid when the gimbal angle is not zero?

Comment: This answer is incorrect and only works with a 0º gimbal pitch and roll (x, y)

Comment: Can you post the Python code as a regular text file on your GitHub page?

Comment: I do not think this is correct, the shape of the footprint is kinda trapezoidal.