# Calculate bounding box coordinates from EXIF data

Tags: exiftool, aerial-photography

I am very much a newbie to this field and I am having problems understanding the mathematical equations given in some of the related questions on other exchange websites.

Basically I want to calculate four coordinates namely, top left, top right, bottom left, bottom right for an image captured by a DJI drone.

I found [How do I calculate the ground footprint of an aerial camera?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/56596/how-do-i-calculate-the-ground-footprint-of-an-aerial-camera) post where the OP has a similar problem.

The accepted answer shows how to calculate the horizontal and ground distance using the EXIF metadata but it doesn't show how to convert it into the bbox coordinates.

Can anyone help me solve this problem?

Comment: What do you call the "bounding box coordinates". A "bounding box" is the smallest (usually axis-aligned) rectangle that encloses a random shape. In a picture the top left corner is `(x=0,y=0)` and the bottom right corner is `(x=width,y=height)`, that are data you can obtain from the Exif or just from the plain image data.

Comment: Basically I want to georeference an image taken from a UAV. As per my initial findings, that can be done using the EXIF data. So by BBOX I meant to calculate  top left, top right, bottom left, bottom right coordinates w.r.t to earth.

Comment: So, you want to compute the longitude/latitude of a pixel in the picture. Well, if you have the longitude/latitude and orientation of the drone, you can use the mentioned formula to compute where the pixel is relative (x,y in meters or d/alpha) to the point directly under the drone, and then compute the longitude/latitude of the pixel from that and the drone position. However this assumes that the ground is flat.